# How can I use Log4J properties map

Tags: java, log4j

Our normal log4j use involves:

```
Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.getName());
logger.error("Some message", someException);
```

I see the LoggingEvent constructor that takes the Map and also its setProperty method but as the Logger method(s) are void (not returning the LoggingEvent), how are they intended to be called?